# How do I import an external class and make an object out of it in Python?

Tags: python

I've Googled around and I just can't seem to find an explicit example of this being done. I created a file called `job.py` for a Job class.

```
class Job(object):
    title = ""
    pay = ""
    description = ""

    def __init__(self, title, pay, description):
        self.title = title
        self.pay = pay
        self.description = description

    def getNoobiness(self):
        return self.title
```

But when I try this in a test file in the same directory:

```
import job

job = Job("Fun Job", "7 elephants", "You will have much fun")
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    job = Job("Fun Job", "7 elephants", "You will have much fun")
NameError: name 'Job' is not defined
```

Comment: first dont name your variable the same as your package. .. second try `from job import Job` or initialize it as `job.Job(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the class from the file:

```
from job import Job
```

Or do this if you want to keep your current import:

```
job.Job(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are importing the module `job` which contains the class `Job`.  However, Python does not know this; as of right now, it has no clue where `Job` is.

To fix the problem, explicitly tell Python where `Job` is by placing `job.` in front of it:

```
import job
new_job = job.Job("Fun Job", "7 elephants", "You will have much fun")
```

Now, Python knows you are using the `Job` class from the `job` module.

---

Or, a cleaner solution would be to just explicitly import `Job`:

```
from job import Job
job = Job("Fun Job", "7 elephants", "You will have much fun")
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley - Just getting to that.  First fix his problem, then tell him the better way. :)